# Release a URL from the routing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tomcat, server

I have created a new application to upload on the same server as my main application.

In this case is a angular app, but can be react, vue or even plain html... the case is I want to be independent.

I have the first one in

```
miapp.com
```

And I want the new one be in

```
miapp.com/otrasapp/minuevaapp
```

but when I try to navigate to it, it redirects me directly to `miapp.com`, I guess because I have the routing

`{path: '**', redirectTo: 'miapp', pathMatch: 'full'}`

What I don't know is how I have to do to allow it to navigate to that address.

P.D: There is also a strange behavior, it does not allow me to access

```
miapp.com/otrasapp/minuevaapp
```

but if a

```
miapp.com/otrasapp/minuevaapp/index.html
```

the problem is that I have to pass parameters to the new app, and if I call

```
miapp.com/otrasapp/minuevaapp/index.html?room=45
```

it gives me a mistake

> Error: Can not match any routes. Segment URL: 'index.html' at
>   ApplyRedirects.push
>   ../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError

In the comments @trichetriche suggests me the problem is not angular but the server. I'm not sure because the warning in the console, but I add the server and tomcat tag.

Comment: No, it redirects you to the root application because your server is setup to redirect you to the root application. All of your questions can't be resolved with Angular : for that, you will need to setup your SERVER. Consider using the correct tags to identify which one you use, so that seomone can answer you.

Answer (score 1):

The error in the console is because your app don't have any route with the index.html path.

Include in your routing:

```
{
 path: 'index.html',
 component: MyComponent,
}
```

Comment: It's works!!! Anyway, the main problem is because the call

`miapp.com/otrasapp/minuevaapp`

It redirects me to

miapp.com

and how to avoid it I still do not know